# Soundcloud player script broken unexpectedly

Tags: soundcloud, soundmanager2

I had worked on a small Soundcloud player and it was working fine for several days, until today. Now it won't load any sound. The web console says:

```
TypeError: SC.streamStopAll is not a function
```

I used this to stop all playing sounds. If I remove it, the sounds load. But I need a way to stop all the sounds. I made no changes to the code, did something change on SC's or SoundManager's side?

Any idea what's going on and how I can fix it?

Comment: well it was working yesterday and most of today. but then they went ahead and broke it again. i don't understand what they're doing but it's not very cool. here's the new error: GET http://connect.soundcloud.com/soundmanager2/soundmanager2_flash9_debug.swf The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: Yes, it's a little frustrating. :( I also notice it's loading both audiomanager and soundmanager (although soundmanager resources 404).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the github repository:

https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/commit/3ee64f9a9864078348a445a51a3b133933ac74b1

They removed soundmanager and replace it with audiomanager. But there is no official documentation about that new audio player. Its also funny that they did not adapt the other API methods that return the stream urls.

Now uses: /tracks/:track_id/streams

But when loading the track data with

```
SC.get('/resolve', "SC_URL", function(){})
```

It still has /tracks/:track_id/stream in the stream_url property.

And the API documentation is also refering to soundmanager.

Comment: Way to not announce this anywhere on the SDK documentation. Thank you for this information.

Comment: OK, this is strange, because now the code is working on Firefox and IE, but not on Chrome. What's going on? :(

Comment: Mm, the console says: GET https://connect.soundcloud.com/audiomanager/audiomanager.js  404 not found. It seems FF and IE are using soundmanager and Chrome is using audiomanager?

Answer (score 2):

The SoundCloud javascript player is broken right now. For everyone. Even on SoundCloud's developer site.

Comment: Good to know, before I go crazy trying to fix it. :) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The SC.stream method will prepare a soundManager2 sound object for the passed track

try : stopAll()

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript  part streaming

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already tried SC.stream.stopAll(), but unfortunately, I'm getting the same error (not a function). It's very odd, since my code didn't change at all, and the player just stopped working. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, I'm loading the SDK from SC's site and letting it load SoundManager on its own.

Comment: Well, from a few other similar questions just posted (players suddenly stopped working without any code change), maybe this is a general problem?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the SoundManager2 Library has been dropped and is replaced with the AudioManager to support RTMP streaming. See this commit: https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/commit/3ee64f9a9864078348a445a51a3b133933ac74b1.